# Building a recommender system for videos from scratch vs. using a SAAS

Tags: recommendation-engine, saas

I have been tasked with developing a recommender system for a video app and am relatively new to data science.

I was wondering whether, given a short time scale of about a month, it would be wiser to turn to a software as a service recommender engine like Recombee or to build the recommender algorithms from scratch using open source software like Apache Spark?

My main hesitation with the first option is that there might not be as much freedom using a SAAS. As such, the recommender system might not be as accurate as building from scratch?

However, I am concerned about the feasibility of creating a recommender system from scratch, especially given my lack of experience. Could I create something within a month that is as accurate and as scalable as using a SAAS?